# Neon sign CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm wanting to create a neon sign of a logo for use on a website and also email signature.

I've a couple of questions I'm hoping a kind person can help me with.

1. For the email signature, I was thinking an animated gif would be best- just to be safe? However, I could use an html template- but I'm unsure the CSS animations used on the website version would render correctly in an (or numerous) email client(s)?
2. I've found this example of a CSS animated neon sign using typed letters in the mark-up. http://www.broken-links.com/tests/animations/

I was wondering if this same CSS animation technique would work with a flat image? How would the CSS know where the edges of the letters are? Would a transparent png work correctly using this technique? I've got the image as pixel or vector based if that helps?

This is a screen shot of the logo and quick mock up style of neon sign I want to create.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Doll logo]

Comment: For your information, many people find those things VERY irritating. Just like beeping and blinking.

Comment: CSS animation in mail clients: absolutely not.

Comment: True that! I'm in that boat. I want it to just flicker on and stay on to be less distracting.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I'll stick to a flicker on gif for mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you linked uses text only. It uses a `@font-face` rule to load a custom font, then animates the colour of the font. Its colour is flat.

What you are attempting to do involves rather more. The easiest solution would probably be to separate each letter into its own image, then you can animate the `opacity` property. This is probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: Animate Opacity you say. I'll look into that. Another question - would this degrade correctly / work on all screens... or am I just hoping for too much?

Comment: Kolink, have you seen an animation tutorial for opacity? Every tutorial I've found seems to talk about opacity in creating a fading image gallery? Also is there a way to apply a sort of text-shadow or drop shadow to re-create that neon effect in browser? (for scaling)?

Comment: For others searching this topic... This link explains a lot http://www.paulund.co.uk/css-animate-effects-we-can-learn-from-animate-css

Comment: Ok update: I've got the opacity flash working using separate png images. However there is a slight gap between images as shown on the white example in this demo link - http://michaelbirchall.com/etc/neon-test/

Comment: Remove the whitespace in your source between the `<img>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if i understand you well.. but this will apply a drop-shadow to a transparent image as applied on the neon text..

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));

filter: url(/assets/svg/shadow.svg#drop-shadow);

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='rgba(0,0,0,0.3)')";

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.S
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure how to implement this? Do I just create a class like logo { your code } and apply that to the transparent image?

Comment: I've found this link to be quite helpful. I'll get back to you with the results. http://www.paulund.co.uk/css-animate-effects-we-can-learn-from-animate-css

Comment: yes, put it in the css.. unless you want to animate it like the neon?!

Answer (score 0):

This link also explains a lot about drop-shadow and box-shadow - due to the browser support it's not quite what I need for my project, but might be useful for someone else searching this drop shadow CSS trick.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison